# Hashing in file instead of memory

Tags: hash

I wanna to ask if there is a way to write a string in a random ((line)) of a file and then searching for it in the same file and get it direct using hash function without collisions.

Comment: There are multiple questions here. First, how to write to (or read from) a random line in a file. Second, how to create a file-based hash map. Third is the problem of a collision-free hash function, which doesn't exist in the general case. It's unclear what you're asking here, and the terseness of your request is a big problem. Please explain in more detail what you're trying to do, and include what you've already tried or what you think would be a good approach to the problem.

Comment: @JimMischel my main question is how to represent hash tabel in binary file. I don't want to create hashtabel as an object and then write it to the file using serialization. I want to construct it in the file so when you write "hello" the program writes it in line4 in the file and so on... and then you can get the line where "hello " is written .

Comment: Before I can provide anything like a reasonable answer, you need to be more specific. Are you trying to store something like a Java `HashMap<K,V>` or C# `Dictionary<Key, Value>`? Edit your question to provide some details.